# How to run Couchbase on multiple server or multiple AWS instances?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, couchbase, membase

I am trying to evaluate couchbase`s performance on multiple nodes. I have a Client that generates data for me based on some schema(for 1 node currently, local). But I want to know how I can horizontally scale Couchbase and how it works. Like If I have multiple machines or AWS instances or Windows Azure how can I configure Couchbase to shard the data and than I can evaluate its performance for multiple nodes. Any suggestions and details as to how I can do this?

Comment: Seems to be pretty decent documentation on [adding nodes to a cluster](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.1/#choosing-when-to-rebalance) on the Couchbase site that appears to answer your question, as it shows how to add nodes to a cluster. And [other docs](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/couchbase-nodes-clusters.html) talk about the fact that Couchbase auto-shards and auto-balances data across nodes. Are you looking for something specific, aside from this? If so, can you please clarify this in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I am not (yet) familiar with Azure but you can find a very good white paper about Couchbase on AWS:

- [Running Couchbase on AWS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/08/running-couchbase-on-aws-new-white-paper.html)

Let's talk about the cluster itself, you just need to

- install Couchbase on multiple nodes
- create a "cluster" on one of then
- then you simply have to add other nodes to the cluster and rebalance.

I have created an Ansible script that use exactly the steps to create a cluster from command line, see

- [Create a Couchbase cluster with Ansible](http://blog.couchbase.com/create-couchbase-cluster-with-ansible)

Once you have done that your application will leverage all the nodes automatically, and you can add/remove nodes as you need.

Finally if you want to learn more about Couchbase architecture, how sharding, failover, data consistency, indexing work, I am inviting your to look at this white paper:

- [Couchbase Server: An Architectural Overview](http://info.couchbase.com/couchbase-server-architecture-review.html)